# Elasticsearch : Disable IDF completely for search result scoring

Tags: java, elasticsearch, tf-idf

This is my sample data in elasticsearch

```
{
    "_index": "12_index",
    "_type": "skill_strings",
    "_id": "AVKv-kM4axmY3fECZw9T",
    "_source": {
       "str": "PHP PHP PHP"
    }
 },
 {
    "_index": "12_index",
    "_type": "skill_strings",
    "_id": "AVKv-kNfaxmY3fECZw9U",
    "_source": {
       "str": "Javascript PHP Javascript Javascript"
    }
 }


"bool":{
  "must":[
    // some conditions
    {"match_phrase":{"str":"php"}}
  ],
  "should":[
    {"match_phrase":{"sentences":"Javascript"}}
  ]
}
```

norms is disable

in the result set, php (with 16 occurrences) gets a score of 13.65 (rounded off) whereas Javascript with the same number of occurrences in another doc gets a lower score of 9.58

As per my use case irrespective of how rare a word is or how short/long the field is, i want a same score for the same term frequency.

How can i do that ?

Comment: To be clear, you want the score to be equal to the number of times the term appears in the indexed document?

Comment: Yes,  but not in the full document, only in the field and for all the term it should remain same as long as the number of occurrences (term frequency) is same

Comment: From a lucene perspective, your str field *is* the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two potential ways:

1) Custom similarity configuration.  See the example here for how this is possible:
 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html#scripted_similarity

2) Create a Scripting Engine:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-engine.html

In most cases, (1) should be easiest.

Comment: some of these functions have been removed from the score_script api: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/30303#issuecomment-385742760

Comment: Thanks!  Updated answer.