# ElasticSearch: Ignore frequency in multi_match query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have query like this:

```
 "body": {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "should": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "iphone",
                        "fields": [
                            "primary.titles^2",
                            "primary.descriptions^1"
                        ],
                        "fuzziness": 1,
                        "prefix_length": 5,
                        "max_expansions": 25,
                        "operator": "and"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must": []
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that docs with title:"iphone/iphone" are scoring much higher than with title:"iphone", **is there any way to ignore repeating of term in search scoring**?

Comment: You can check `constant_score` query but it will not boost based on field as you have done for title and description.

Comment: Thanks, but documentation says that it "returns every matching document with a relevance score equal to the boost parameter value."  I guess it would set statical score to all results and it makes sort by scoring useless.

Comment: Yes, True. it will assign constant score based on value of boost param.

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35307512/5489276) SO answer for custom scoring based on terms.

Comment: Sagar Patel, would it be an option to add a term match in the "should" clause? I remember in some post that they used this strategy to improve the score.

Comment: rabbitbr what you mean? Use match instead of multi_match?

Comment: "[match] query doesn't support multiple fields"

Comment: Sagar Patel thanks. Overwrite ES search algorithm looks too hard... I'll try it if there wouldn't be any other way :D